# match and merge two different files based on common columns

Tags: regex, unix, merge, match

I am trying to match and extract some list from two files. I will explain it better with an example.

I have two files

```
List
gene1
gene2
gene3

MainFile
chr17   70593167    70593381    exon    .   +   gene10
chr17   70593167    70593381    intron  .   +   gene1
```

1. I would like to match and extract from MainFile the list of genes. Output for this one will be

   `chr17  70593167    70593381    intron  .   +   gene1`
2. I would like to find the non-matching ones as well. Output for this one will be

   `chr17   70593167    70593381    exon    .   +   gene10`

Comment: Check out the `join` program...

Comment: does join work if there is multiple matches?

Comment: It should. At least the version I have does - but there may be different implementations out there, so check yours out. Do note, though that both input files need to be sorted on the join key...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
egrep "$(echo $(<List)|sed 's/ /$|/g')$" MainFile > Matches
egrep -v "$(echo $(<List)|sed 's/ /$|/g')$" MainFile > NonMatches
```

It transforms List into a regex with the help of sed and bash substitution, then uses egrep to search through MainFile.

This may not work well if List is a big file.

Comment: thanks, but it is a bit slow as the data i have is big

Answer (score 0):

This ruby solution should be faster than my shell version:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

list = File.read("List").split
File.open("Matches","w"){|match|
  File.open("NonMatches","w"){|non|
    File.open("MainFile").each{|line|
      if list.include?(line.split[6])
        match.print(line)
      else
        non.print(line)
      end
    }
  }
}
```